# Grouping multiple websites under the same URL

Tags: url, dns, domain-name

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I set up websites on multiple hosts using the same domain name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949758/can-i-set-up-websites-on-multiple-hosts-using-the-same-domain-name)

I'm trying to run multiple sites from the same domain.

So if I have a blog, a main site and a shop section I want to be able to list them as.

- blog.example.com, the blog
- www.example.com, main site
- store.example.com, the shop

The sites are all hosted at different places.

My question is almost identical to this one [Can I set up websites on multiple hosts using the same domain name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949758/can-i-set-up-websites-on-multiple-hosts-using-the-same-domain-name)
With one solution being the use of the DNS settings. How is this accomplished or can I be linked to literature where I can learn myself.

I am very very new to web development. If you require any other information let me know.

Comment: The answer will depend on which server software you are using. Please specify what platform you're on, or if you're open to suggestions for this. Also, this should probably be on Server Fault.

Comment: fasthosts for the main site and Vidahost for the store

Comment: Sorry didn't know about server fault. Should I just start a new question there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this previous answer can help you out

> https://serverfault.com/questions/109049/how-to-point-subdomain-to-another-server-that-does-not-have-a-domain-yet

It addresses pointing a subdomain to another server that doesn't have a domain specified. But there is emphasis on pointing the subdomain to another server.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you that helped a lot. I now have the shop at shop.mydomain.com. However I still want the extensions to be shown like shop.mydomain.com/products/hat. Is this possible?